# Java: Method returns object that eclipse can't find

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

Right now i'm making a Bukkit plugin for Minecraft(1.6.4) server with Cauldron core. Cauldron core has a class called CustomModRecipe, which has method called getHandle(). This method returns an "aah" object. And the problem is that i can't create variable that can store this "aah" object. But if i use that object directly, eclipse shows me different methods i can use for that object(like a(), B() and etc). After some searching i find a jar that contains these weird named classes, but including it didn't change anything. Here i show what code i have:

```
Iterator<Recipe> iterator = Bukkit.recipeIterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Recipe rec= iterator.next();
    if(rec instanceof CustomModRecipe){
        // CustomModRecipe.getHandle() returns aah object
        // But Eclipse says that "aah cannot be resolved to a type"
        aah recHandle = ((CustomModRecipe) rec).getHandle();
        // Method aah.b() return object "ye", that can't be stored too
        ye someVar = ((CustomModRecipe) rec).getHandle().b();
        // Why is this working so weird?
    }
}
```

Comment: Please set the full method defination not the inner logic.

Comment: Is "aah" really a class name ?

Comment: Yes it is, like i understood, real name of that class before obfuscation was IRecipe, but now it has name aah. I even included jar that has these obfuscated classes, but no changes, still eclipse can't resolve them

Comment: Please stay within java naming conventions (first letter of a class is a capital letter, camel case etc.) otherwise the code will become unreadable!

Comment: Good luck trying to use obfuscated libs. Some classes or methods will probably have java keywords as a name, making your code unable  to compile. Moreover, trying to understand what "a" ,"aah", "b()" are or do, is real overkill.

Comment: Could it be not "aah", but something very similar? LIke, "ааh", maybe? See, it looks the same, but I put Cyrillic "аа" in the second one.